# PostgreSQL query filtering results by conditions based on jsonb

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

I have a data in my DB similar to next rows:

| id | code | custom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GOOG | [{"customBreakdown":{"id":15,"name":"By PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"team"}},{"customBreakdown":{"id":14,"name":"By SOW"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"poland"}}] |
| 2 | GOOG | [{"customBreakdown":{"id":15,"name":"By SOW"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"team"}},{"customBreakdown":{"id":17,"name":"By SOW/PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"poland"}}] |
| 3 | GOOG | [{"customBreakdown":{"id":15,"name":"By PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"team"}},{"customBreakdown":{"id":14,"name":"By SOW"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":73,"name":"Ungrouped"}}] |
| 4 | GOOG | [{"customBreakdown":{"id":15,"name":"By PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"team"}},{"customBreakdown":{"id":14,"name":"By SOW/PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":73,"name":"Ungrouped"}}] |
| 5 | GOOG | [] |
| 12 | AW | [{"customBreakdown":{"id":15,"name":"By PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"team"}},{"customBreakdown":{"id":17,"name":"By SOW/PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"poland"}}] |
| 13 | AW | [{"customBreakdown":{"id":15,"name":"By PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"team"}},{"customBreakdown":{"id":14,"name":"By SOW"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":73,"name":"Ungrouped"}}] |
| 14 | AW | [{"customBreakdown":{"id":15,"name":"By PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"team"}},{"customBreakdown":{"id":14,"name":"By SOW/PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":73,"name":"Ungrouped"}}] |
| 15 | AW | [] |

making sql query I need as result all `code`s + `customBreakdownName` + `customBreakdownGroupName` where

- custom[any obj]->'customBreakdown'->>'name' = 'By SOW' and custom[any obj in arr]->'customBreakdownGroup'->>'name' != 'Ungrouped'
- if previous conditions doesn't met but code present, return the `code` and empty `customBreakdownName` and `customBreakdownGroupName`

the query to table above have to return next result:

| code | customBreakdownName | customBreakdownGroupName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GOOG | By SOW | poland |
| GOOG | By SOW | team |
| AW | NULL | NULL |

My query that I've implemented needs more complex condition to manage last row as result.

### P.S.

[Prepared PostgreSQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pww0TTUB)

Or if you prefer manage solution without fiddle you can use next data.

Postgresql table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    id int,
    code text,
    custom text
);

INSERT INTO a VALUES
(1,'GOOG','[{"customBreakdown":{"id":15,"name":"By PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"team"}},{"customBreakdown":{"id":14,"name":"By SOW"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"poland"}}]'),
(2,'GOOG','[{"customBreakdown":{"id":15,"name":"By SOW"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"team"}},{"customBreakdown":{"id":17,"name":"By SOW/PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"poland"}}]'),
(3,'GOOG','[{"customBreakdown":{"id":15,"name":"By PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"team"}},{"customBreakdown":{"id":14,"name":"By SOW"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":73,"name":"Ungrouped"}}]'),
(4,'GOOG','[{"customBreakdown":{"id":15,"name":"By PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"team"}},{"customBreakdown":{"id":14,"name":"By SOW/PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":73,"name":"Ungrouped"}}]')
 ,
(5,'GOOG','[]')--
--(6,''),
--(7,null)
,(12,'AW','[{"customBreakdown":{"id":15,"name":"By PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"team"}},{"customBreakdown":{"id":17,"name":"By SOW/PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"poland"}}]'),
(13,'AW','[{"customBreakdown":{"id":15,"name":"By PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"team"}},{"customBreakdown":{"id":14,"name":"By SOW"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":73,"name":"Ungrouped"}}]'),
(14,'AW','[{"customBreakdown":{"id":15,"name":"By PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":72,"name":"team"}},{"customBreakdown":{"id":14,"name":"By SOW/PO"},"customBreakdownGroup":{"id":73,"name":"Ungrouped"}}]')
 ,
(15,'AW','[]')--,
  ;

-- SELECT * FROM a;
```

My query (which requires a fix):

```
SELECT 
  code
--  ,custom
  ,arr.item_object->'customBreakdown'->>'name' as customBreakdownName
  ,arr.item_object->'customBreakdownGroup'->>'name' as customBreakdownGroupName
FROM a
left join jsonb_array_elements(a.custom::JSONB) with ordinality arr(item_object) on true
where arr.item_object->'customBreakdown'->>'name' = 'By SOW'
  and arr.item_object->'customBreakdownGroup'->>'name' != 'Ungrouped'
--  or arr.item_object->'customBreakdown'->>'name' != 'By SOW'
--  and 
-- or a.custom::jsonb = '[]'
```

It requires fix because returns different result:

| code | customBreakdownName | customBreakdownGroupName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GOOG | By SOW | poland |
| GOOG | By SOW | team |

Comment: The column `custom` should be defined as `jsonb`, not as `text`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I provided table fields very close to original ones. The type is the same there. That's not an issue, but if you are more comfortable to provide solution where `custom` is `jsonb` type, you are welcome! I'll accept any correct answer.

Comment: I don't understand the condition why `AW` should be returned - presumably the row with `ID = 15`  but not the row with `ID = 5` where the `custom` column is also an empty array

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, the row with `ID=5` (like `3` or `4`) should be skipped because we met first condition combination, in case first condition combination doesn't have any match, we need manage second condition part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with multiple "with" statements:

- first flatten the array in JSONB
- then find all unique codes
- then filter flattened rows based on your condition
- then join unique codes with matching rows to get the result.

```
WITH flattened AS (SELECT 
  code,
  jsonb_array_elements(custom::jsonb) as cust
FROM a),
all_codes AS (SELECT DISTINCT code FROM a),
matching AS (SELECT code,
  cust->'customBreakdown'->'name' AS customBreakdown,
  cust->'customBreakdownGroup'->'name' AS customBreakdownGroup
FROM flattened
WHERE cust->'customBreakdown'->'name' = '"By SOW"' AND cust->'customBreakdownGroup'->'name' != '"Ungrouped"')
SELECT 
  all_codes.code,
  matching.customBreakdown,
  matching.customBreakdownGroup
FROM all_codes
LEFT JOIN matching ON all_codes.code = matching.code
```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/AFzoJwfS

Comment: I really confused. It works correctly but i have no idea why (as i remember standard query starts with `select * from ...`). Is it single query? In case my query will be more complex because of performance optimisation may I have `WITH flattened` inside of join?

Comment: In Postgresql you can use "with" (aka common table expressions) to produce somewhat like "temporary" tables from which the latter queries can fetch the data. Actually I'm not sure if it is the most efficient way in terms of used RAM, but it looks like linear scan of table so no N^2 or other irregularities expected. Also I'm sure the task is also achievable without "with" but I can't figure how off top of my head.